# Why am I getting NaN values in this data process in Python?

Tags: python, csv, nan

I am trying to get the mean of these four artists from a CSV in its respective features but I am obtaining those NaN values.

IMHO I think it is because in the CSV are many zeros, but then I try to plot the 'acousticness' frequency from 'Extremoduro' and I get the plot with values of.

I tried to put the mean value to the column but it still remains the NaN value. Also, I tried to change the column format to int, but nothing happened too.

This is my code:

```
import numpy as np

result=[]
audio_features=['danceability','energy','key','loudness','mode','speechiness','acousticness','instrumentalness',
            'liveness','valence','tempo','duration_ms']
 artists=["Metallica", "Extremoduro", "AC/DC", "Hans Zimmer"]
 for a in artists:
        for v in audio_features:
                result.append(np.nanmean(df[v].loc[df['name_artist'] == a]))
```

Output:

```
                  Metallica  Extremoduro       AC/DC    Hans Zimmer
 danceability       0.349569     0.846328    5.425641      -7.707323
 energy             0.581538     0.098277    0.082615       0.280533
 key                0.413364     0.317938  122.677641  333602.843077
 loudness           0.409805     0.794935    5.857143      -7.786104
 mode               0.571429     0.084675    0.148247       0.169221
 speechiness        0.277273     0.483052  139.082468  257855.370130
 acousticness            NaN          NaN         NaN            NaN
 instrumentalness        NaN          NaN         NaN            NaN
 liveness                NaN          NaN         NaN            NaN
 valence            0.282199     0.269810    4.561889     -18.791699
 tempo              0.593920     0.046895    0.579343       0.742351
 duration_ms        0.159604     0.139642  107.293903  245953.425081
```

Then, if I do this:

```
import numpy as np

result=[]
audio_features=['danceability','energy','key','loudness','mode','speechiness','acousticness','instrumentalness','liveness','valence','tempo','duration_ms']
 artists=["Metallica", "Extremoduro", "AC/DC", "Hans Zimmer"]
 for a in artists:
        for v in audio_features:
                result.append(np.nanmean(df[v].loc[df['name_artist'] == a]))
```

Output:

```
              Metallica  Extremoduro   AC/DC  Hans Zimmer
danceability       0.35         0.85    5.43        -7.71
energy             0.58         0.10    0.32       122.68
key           333602.84         0.41    0.79         5.86
loudness          -7.79         0.57    0.08         0.48
mode             139.08    257855.37     NaN          NaN
speechiness         NaN          NaN     NaN          NaN
valence             NaN          NaN     NaN         0.28
tempo              0.27         4.56  -18.79         0.59
duration_ms        0.05         0.14  107.29    245953.43
```

On the other hand, if I try to do this in my code, it actually return me a float value:

Input:

`a=df['acousticness'].loc[df['name_artist'] == "Metallica"].mean()`

Output:
`0.08261538461538463`

This is my full code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


dataset=pd.read_csv('df.csv')

result=[]
audio_features=['danceability','energy','key','loudness','mode','speechiness','acousticness','instrumentalness',
        'liveness','valence','tempo','duration_ms']
artists=["Metallica", "Extremoduro", "AC/DC", "Hans Zimmer"]
for a in artists:
    for v in audio_features:
        result.append(df[v].loc[df['name_artist'] == a].mean())

result=np.reshape(result,(len(audio_features),len(artists)))
dataset=pd.DataFrame(result,audio_features,artists).round(2)
print(dataset)
```

Answer (score 0):

The source data may be missing, `NaN` or the incorrect DataType. You can try to fix the input `csv` file, or use [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) to fill any `NaN` values with 0.

```
df = df.fillna(0)
```

Comment: I have checked my data and did what you told me and I still have the same problem.

Comment: Can you share the data and the full code to troubleshoot?

Comment: There it is the full code and the link to the CSV. Thank you DogEatDog. So basically, what I am trying to do is to get the mean values of the audiofeatures[] from the different artists[].

Comment: Hi DogEatDog, I found out that the problem was that the input name 'AC/DC' had to be in title() case like this: 'Ac/Dc'. Sorry for losing your time and thank you very very much. I appreciate it.

Comment: No worries. Sometimes I convert the column headers to all upper or lower case to avoid weird errors like this from bad data.